# input date picker on android shows wrong picker on WebView

Tags: android, webview, datepicker

I've got an HTML5 INPUT (type="datetime-local") in a WebView, but when I select it, it shows a date-time field that looks like this:

[image]

But the same identical element in Chrome looks like this:

[image]

This is under Android 7.1, with Chrome v55 installed, so Chrome is being used the WebView component.  So, both should show the same thing, right?

I need the latter picker to show up in the WebView, it is much more user friendly (to scroll you can just flick up and down rather than having to repeatedly press the plus or minute buttons.

How do I accomplish this?

Update: I have tried creating this natively using a `DatePickerDialog` and it does the same thing!  I'm targeting minSdkVersion=22, targetSdkVersion=25 (although I have also tried minSdkVersion=25).  How do I force Android to display the correct picker for my app?

Update 2: I downloaded a  sample app using the native DatePickerDialog and it displays the dialog ok.  I don't like the idea of having to try to find the difference between the two projects which is causing the behavioral difference as it could be anything and take an excessive amount of time to find.

Update 3: Using the answer provided by Oleg, I was able to reproduce the second picker using `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`.  But if I use `android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light` I can get a calendar view for `input type="date"`.  But the corresponding time picker in the Default theme (the round clock) does *not* show up for `input type="time"` and ``input type="datetime-local"` doesn't use the calendar view either.

Comment: it could be a theme used by your app and test app, have you compared those?

Comment: not directly, although this may be promising... I dropped the compat library of the working example, got errors relating to theme, switched to a theme that worked, and the picker appearances changed!

Comment: @OlegBogdanov Wow, sure enough I changed the theme to "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" and now it works!  Make that an answer and I'll upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you are likely missing the proper theme. Given that you have access to working app, please apply the same theme, it should solve it

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the application setting. Steps are below:-

**1.** Add the dependency on Android’s Material in ***/android/app/build.gradle***:

```
    dependencies {
    //..
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    }
```

you will found the latest version here:- https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material

**2.** Set the light theme in ***/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml***:

```
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

**3.** Set the dark theme in ***/android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml***

```
<style name="NormalTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
</style>
```